# Python/Pygame: How to save text box input as variable

Tags: python, variables, input, module, pygame

I am currently using this bit of code I found:

http://www.pygame.org/project-PyInputBox-2893-.html

It is quite a good way of creating text boxes that users can input into within a pygame window. Basically I want to be able to save their input into a variable I can use at a later point, but not sure how I would go about it.

Cheers for the help in advance.

Comment: Get it using the `text` variable. In the example on PyGame.org, `inp.lst[0].text`

Answer (score 2):

After creating a `text_box`, the text is stored in `text_box.text`

```
mytextbox = text_box(i omitted the arguments)
textinbox = mytextbox.text
print(textinbox)
```